# Narrow down TypeScript action type when using typesafe-actions's createAsyncAction

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, typesafe-actions

When using [`typesafe-actions`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions) we can create an action without using constants in our application like so:

```
export const toggle = createStandardAction('todos/TOGGLE')<string>();
```

And then in the reducer we would do something like this to narrow down the type on each `case` block:

```
import { ActionType, getType } from 'typesafe-actions';
import * as todos from './actions';

type TodosAction = ActionType<typeof todos>;

export default (state: Todo[] = [], action: TodosAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case getType(todos.add):
            // Below action type is narrowed to: { type: "todos/ADD"; payload: Todo; }
            return [...state, action.payload];

        ...

        default:
            return state;
}
```

However, in my case, I'm using the [`async-flow`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#--the-async-flow), so my actions look like this:

```
import { ActionType, createAsyncAction } from 'typesafe-actions';

import {
    getAsyncFetchActionConstants,
    getAsyncCreateActionConstants,
    getAsyncDeleteActionConstants,
} from '../utils/asyncActions.utils';

const BASE_ACTION = 'AUTH';

export const fetchAuth = createAsyncAction(
    ...getAsyncFetchActionConstants(BASE_ACTION))<void, AuthState, Error>();

export const createAuth = createAsyncAction(
    ...getAsyncCreateActionConstants(BASE_ACTION))<void, AuthState, Error>();

export const deleteAuth = createAsyncAction(
    ...getAsyncDeleteActionConstants(BASE_ACTION))<void, AuthState, Error>();

export type AuthRequestActions
    = ActionType<typeof fetchAuth.request> | ActionType<typeof createAuth.request> | ActionType<typeof deleteAuth.request>;

export type AuthSuccessActions
    = ActionType<typeof fetchAuth.success> | ActionType<typeof createAuth.success> | ActionType<typeof deleteAuth.success>;

export type AuthErrorActions
    = ActionType<typeof fetchAuth.failure> | ActionType<typeof createAuth.failure> | ActionType<typeof deleteAuth.failure>;

export type AuthActions = AuthRequestActions | AuthSuccessActions | AuthErrorActions;
```

`getAsync[Fetch|Create|Delete]ActionConstants` are just helper functions that return an array of 3 strings:

```
export function getAsyncActionConstants(actionName, entityName): [string, string, string] {
    return [
        `${ actionName }_${ entityName }_${ ASYNC_REQUEST }`,
        `${ actionName }_${ entityName }_${ ASYNC_SUCCESS }`,
        `${ actionName }_${ entityName }_${ ASYNC_FAILURE }`,
    ];
}
```

And in my reducer I have:

```
import { getType } from 'typesafe-actions';

import { AUTH_INITIAL_STATE } from './auth.constants';
import { fetchAuth, createAuth, deleteAuth, AuthActions, AuthActions } from './auth.actions';

export function authReducer(state: AuthState = AUTH_INITIAL_STATE, action: AuthActions) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case getType(fetchAuth.success):
            // TS ERROR: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'AuthActions'. Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'EmptyAction<string>'.
            return action.payload;

        ...

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to get this working as in the first (non-async) example without casting.

Also, it would be great if someone can suggest how to generate the `type AuthActions` without so much boilerplate.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use 'dynamic' strings to define the action constants, and have the TypeScript type resolution work in the switch statement - they can only be string literals. So your 'getAsyncActionConstants' function is the problem. See the notes here: https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#constants